# Bring Git Development branch in line with Master branch post deployment

Tags: git, github, version-control, branching-and-merging

I am using GitHub to host the files for a static site before they are deployed. There are 2 branches, `master` and `development`. Work is done by a branch off of `development` and then a pull request is raised to merge those changes into `development`. When all the development changes are merged in, a pull request is raised to merge into `master` which then kicks off the automatic deployment of the site.

`dev-branch` -> `development` -> `master`

Once both of the pull requests are complete, the `master` branch is 1 commit ahead of the `development` branch (which is the additional pull request). I want to bring the `development` branch back in line with `master` with the same number of commits, as `development` is the branch that new branches stem from for further development.

My current process is to checkout my local `master` and then pull the remote changes:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
```

I then checkout my local `development` and pull the remote `master` changes again:

```
$ git checkout development
$ git pull origin master
```

This puts the remote `master`, the local `master` and the local `development` at the same point. I then push my local `development` to the remote `development` to align both remote and both local branches:

```
$ git push origin development
```

Is there any easier way to have the `master` branch changes reflected in the `development` branch? Both branches are protected to prevent unauthorised changes and I am using my admin rights to get this last push to go through.

I have based my process off this model: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and want to have the `development` branch to allow me to check content before the pull request to `master` as that approval causes automatic deployment of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I was previously pulling the changes from each of the remote branches to the local branches. I think the better option is to pull the `master` branch and then merge the remaining branches locally before pushing those changes to the remote.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git checkout development
$ git merge master
$ git push origin development
```

This can be repeated for each individual feature development branch that is then merged with the development branch.